# Codeigniter - Get data from the database and compare them within the model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to know if it is possible to obtain data from the database within the model, with an array and then compare them to any side logic model and then pass them to controllador.

**Questions:**

It is advisable to do this?

You can get the data from the model, as is done in the driver?

```
public function get_country( $country_id = '' )
{
    $this->db->select('id, name');
    $this->db->where('id', $country_id );
    $query = $this->db->get('country');
    $query->row_array();

    if( $query[0]['id'] == 1 && $query[0]['name'] == 'EEUU' ) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

*I would greatly appreciate your help!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly acceptable and many would say the correct approach. But your code isn't going to work as shown. Try this...

```
  public function get_country($country_id = '')
  {
    //I am using method chaining here... it's more efficient, 
    $query = $this->db->select('id, name')
      ->where('id', $country_id)
      ->get('country');

    $row = $query->row_array();  //returns a single row

    if($row['id'] == 1 && $row['name'] == 'EEUU')
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
  }
```

You will find many people that regard the Model as the place for all business logic. Lots of talk about 'fat' Models and 'skinny' Controllers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the support, it worked perfectly.

Comment: How it works using result_array(), This way is correct? $row[0]['field];

Comment: Yes, that works. Think of result_array() as an array full of row_array() returns. With this line `$records = $query->result_array();` it can be handy to use a loop to process the return like this. `foreach ($records as $row)
{ $foo = $row['field1']; $bar = $row['field2']; ... }`